# Div Resize not working on Internet explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div that I'm resizing through simple css that resizes beautifully on chrome , firefox , and some other browsers however it doesn't seem to do anything on internet explorer. I have put my code below to have a look at it as I'm not sure what I'm missing. I'd prefer if possible to keep the solution within css but if I need to implement something else I am open to options and any help. Thank you.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
      <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
      <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes, width=device-width">
      <meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="true">
      <meta name="MobileOptimized" content="width">
      <style type="text/css">
         * { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
         html, body { width: 100%; height: 100%; overflow: hidden; color: #ffffff; background-color: #000000; }
         #banner { width: 100%; height: 100%; border: none; overflow: hidden; float:left; z-index:9; }
         #BodyContainer { position: absolute; top: 150px; left: 0px; bottom: 0px; right: 0px; clear: both; }
         #bottom { width: 100%; height: 100%; border: none; }
         .resizable {
         resize: vertical;
         display: block;
         width: 100%;
         height: 120px;
         border: 2px black;
         overflow: hidden;
         position: relative;
         box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #33A6A6;
         z-index:9;
         }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div></div>
      <div class="resizable">
         <iframe width="100%" height="100%" id="banner" name="BANNER" src="$BASE$/BANNER?$CONFIG$"></iframe>
      </div>
      <div></div>
      <div id="BodyContainer">
         <div></div>
         <iframe width="100%" height="100%" id="bottom" name="BODY" src="$BASE$/BODY?$CONFIG$"></iframe>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are resizing the div using CSS, the `resize` property is not yet supported in IE, if you want to achieve this effect on all browsers then I recommend using jQuery resizable, [here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TPZ5K/) that demonstrates using it.

Please note that this requires jQuery and jQuery UI libraries.

Comment: Thanks Karim I appreciate the confirmation I wasn't quite sure if that was the case or not so I'll look into doing it with jquery.

Comment: In Continuation of this i would like to ask , resizable is a jquery-ui function is there a way i can do it in javascript or css not using jquery -ui  lib, an alternate method